# Snapping to grid doesn't work

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I am trying to do snapping on grid such that whatever I will draw it should take only gridpoints and no other points. I have made grid in cadgraphicsscene.cpp and made different class for snapping. 
My grid is made as follows:

cadgraphicscene.cpp

```
void CadGraphicsScene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    const int gridSize = 50;
    const int realLeft = static_cast<int>(std::floor(rect.left()));
    const int realRight = static_cast<int>(std::ceil(rect.right()));
    const int realTop = static_cast<int>(std::floor(rect.top()));
    const int realBottom = static_cast<int>(std::ceil(rect.bottom()));

    // Draw grid.
    const int firstLeftGridLine = realLeft - (realLeft % gridSize);
    const int firstTopGridLine = realTop - (realTop % gridSize);
    QVarLengthArray<QLine, 100> lines;

    for (qreal x = firstLeftGridLine; x <= realRight; x += gridSize)
        lines.append(QLine(x, realTop, x, realBottom));
    for (qreal y = firstTopGridLine; y <= realBottom; y += gridSize)
        lines.append(QLine(realLeft, y, realRight, y));

    painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(220, 220, 220), 0.0));
    painter->drawLines(lines.data(), lines.size());

    // Draw axes.
    painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::lightGray, 0.0));
    painter->drawLine(0, realTop, 0, realBottom);
    painter->drawLine(realLeft, 0, realRight, 0);
}
```

My snap class looks as follows:

snap.cpp

```
#include "snap.h"
#include <QApplication>

    Snap::Snap(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent,
               QGraphicsScene* scene):
    QGraphicsRectItem(QRectF())
    {
        setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable |
                QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable |
                QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
    }

    void Snap::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
        offset = pos() - computeTopLeftGridPoint(pos());
        QGraphicsRectItem::mousePressEvent(event);
    }

    QVariant Snap::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,
    const QVariant &value)
    {
        if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) {
            QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
            if(QApplication::mouseButtons() == Qt::LeftButton &&
                qobject_cast<CadGraphicsScene*> (scene())){
                    QPointF closestPoint = computeTopLeftGridPoint(newPos);
                    return closestPoint+=offset;
                }
            else
                return newPos;
        }
        else
            return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
    }

    QPointF Snap::computeTopLeftGridPoint(const QPointF& pointP){
       CadGraphicsScene* customScene = qobject_cast<CadGraphicsScene*> (scene());
        int gridSize = customScene->getGridSize();
        qreal xV = floor(pointP.x()/gridSize)*gridSize;
        qreal yV = floor(pointP.y()/gridSize)*gridSize;
        return QPointF(xV, yV);
    }
```

snap.h

```
#ifndef SNAP_H
#define SNAP_H

#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include "cadgraphicsscene.h"

class Snap : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    Snap(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent,
         QGraphicsScene* scene);
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,
    const QVariant &value);
private:
    QPointF offset;
    QPointF computeTopLeftGridPoint(const QPointF &pointP);
};

#endif // SNAP_H
```

But nothing happened, no snapping is done. Can you please help me in the above?

Comment: Try some debugging. See how far it goes into the `itemChange` function.

Comment: When I run the debugger it doesn't stop anywhere. I am unable to get where is the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Add break points and start stepping through.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please help me out...

Comment: If you are using Qt creator, read about [debugging in the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-debugging.html). More specifically about [interacting with the debugger](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-debug-mode.html).

Comment: It doesnt stop anywhere in Qvariant functiion

Comment: Did you enable the `QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag? From the docs: [*QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange: The item's position changes. This notification is sent if the ItemSendsGeometryChanges flag is enabled, and when the item's local position changes, relative to its parent (i.e., as a result of calling setPos() or moveBy()).*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemChange-enum)

Comment: Yes, I have set the flag in the constructor of snap.cpp

Comment: And you're saying even if you move the item the `itemChange` method is not called?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same thing I want to convey

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Include `QDebug` header and add `qDebug() << "inside itemchange function";` in the first line of the  `ItemChange` function and see if it gets displayed in the application output.

Comment: No debug doesn't works. Inside itemChange doesn't get printed.

Comment: Could you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Basically just have the main function where you create a `QGraphicsView` (do not subclass this, just create the default view), and add one of your `Snap` items to it. So the project should look like this: `main.cpp`, `snap.h`, `snap.cpp`.

Comment: The point of SSCCE is to decouple everything. It was easy to do, just remove the `cadgraphicsscene.h` dependency from the `Snap` class. Anyway I did it for you. One problem is how you call the `QGraphicsRectItem` constructor. You call it with an empty `QRect`. You shouldn't even get any rectangles in your scene. You pass a `const QRect &` to your `Snap` constructor, you might as well pass that to the base class constructor. I'd also like to comment on your design. `Snap` should not get the grid size from the `CadGraphicsScene`. `CadGraphicsScene` should tell `Snap` what the grid size is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that you pass `QRect()` to the `QGraphicsRectItem` constructor in the initialization list of `Snap` class. This means it will have 0 width and height. Instead pass the same `QRect` object that you pass to your snap constructor:

```
Snap::Snap(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent, QGraphicsScene* scene) :
QGraphicsRectItem(rect)
```

You also don't seem to use the parent and the scene arguments so you might as well leave them out:

```
Snap::Snap(const QRect& rect) :
    QGraphicsRectItem(rect)
```

Or if you plan to use the parent for something then you can set a default value to 0 in the declaration:

```
Snap(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent = 0);
```

Then pass them both to the base class constructor:

```
Snap::Snap(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent) :
QGraphicsRectItem(rect, parent)
```

*snap.h*

```
#ifndef SNAP_H
#define SNAP_H

#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class Snap : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    Snap(const QRect &rect, QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,
    const QVariant &value);
private:
    QPointF offset;
    QPointF computeTopLeftGridPoint(const QPointF &pointP);
};

#endif // SNAP_H
```

*snap.cpp*

```
#include "snap.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <qmath.h>

Snap::Snap(const QRect& rect, QGraphicsItem* parent) :
    QGraphicsRectItem(rect, parent)
{
    setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
}

void Snap::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    offset = pos() - computeTopLeftGridPoint(pos());
    QGraphicsRectItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}

QVariant Snap::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,
                          const QVariant &value)
{
    qDebug()<<"inside itemChange";
    if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene())
    {
        QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
        QPointF closestPoint = computeTopLeftGridPoint(newPos);
        return closestPoint+=offset;
    }
    else
        return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}

QPointF Snap::computeTopLeftGridPoint(const QPointF& pointP){
    int gridSize = 100;
    qreal xV = qFloor(pointP.x()/gridSize)*gridSize;
    qreal yV = qFloor(pointP.y()/gridSize)*gridSize;
    return QPointF(xV, yV);
}
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLayout>
#include "snap.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(view);
    Snap *snap = new Snap(QRect(0,0,100,100));
    view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
    view->scene()->addItem(snap);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```